# Python regex understanding

Tags: python

I just started learning Python coming from c and PHP.
I'm having a hard time using a simple regex match.

I have files which are read into a string, then I'm trying to match a needle in this string which never works though

```
accounts=list(set(accounts))

cpanelAccountList = open("/etc/userdomains", "r")

lines = cpanelAccountList.read()

for account in accounts:
    pattern='%s: (.*)'%account
    print re.findall(pattern,lines)
```

This always returns None. I tried several online regex builders and the pattern seems to work there, but I can not get it to work.

Part of the text of file which I read into lines variable:

```
 sawpalmetto-asia.com: sawpalme
 gbbco.ir: gbbco
 golshanirad.7pd.ir: pdir
 bibi-co.com: bibico
 venushandle.ir: handle
 spa.ami3en.com: ami3en
 pishtazansanaat.ir: pishtaz
 tablojahan.com: jahan1
```

And an accounts list variable  sample:

```
['spa.ami3en.com','gbbco.ir']
```

Comment: What type of pattern(s) do you want to have? What is your expected result?

Comment: `re.findall('spa.ami3en.com: (.*)', 'spa.ami3en.com: ami3en')` matches fine for me. I mean, the expression probably isn't what you had in mind what with `.` there, but it does happen to find matches. Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Print out account, are you sure it's in the lines?

Comment: Im trying to extract what ever comes(usernames) after the colon , where beginning matches the list i have as accounts variable

Comment: be aware that `re.findall(pattern, ...)` is not searching for the pattern you had in mind. `"spa.ami3en.com"` counts those dots (`.`) as "any character," not literal dots. You can use `re.escape` to escape out literal strings for use in regex. `pattern = "{}: (.*)".format(re.escape(account))` (that said, "any character" should also match the literal dot so that's not the issue at hand here)

Comment: Your code with the data provided works for me in Python version 2.7.5